# Solving modular equations with modulus fixed

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modular-forms

A solution $0<x<29$ exists for:

$x^2(x+2)\equiv1\pmod{29}$

How would one solve for $x$ in this case? (Writing the factored polynomial in standard form would be a good way to start but where do you go from there?) Please show work and steps just like in algebra.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $x^2(x+2)-1=(x+1)\left(x^2+x-1\right)$

Comment: i have found $$5,23,28$$